# I'm in Australia and want to trade US stocks. Is it better to use an Australian broker or US?

Tags: united-states, trading

I could open an International trading account with e.g. CBA or ANZ, or sign with US online broker, e.g. ETrade, Ameritrade etc. What are the pros and cons?

My strategy is long term buy and hold, so I'm not too concerned with trade costs, more currency conversion, taxes, convenience etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have US stock as a non-US citizen living in Europe. I used to work for a company where we were given stock benefits using a US broker.

The drawback of using a US broker is that you have to sign extra papers where you claim that you have absolutely no connection to US whatsoever. If you don't sign those papers, you will have to pay extra tax. New forms will be periodically required, so this is not just "sign once and forget" thing.

Based on this, I would recommend using an Australian broker, if your time has any value at all (you mentioned convenience, so there probably is some value for your time). Also, if you need to call the broker for any reason, you can call an Australian broker easily due to no time zone differences. The same cannot be said for US brokers.